# Conditional IF doesn't work

Tags: vba

I have the following code

```
    Option Explicit

Public Sub SegmentLengths()
Dim r, k, j, n As Integer
Dim Li(18), Lseg, M, x, x1, x2, xi, span As Double

xi = Range("B3").Value / 100      'incremento coordinata
n = Range("C72").Value    'nb of lateral restraints
span = xi * 100
Lseg = span / n                       'typ segment length
r = 1
While Cells(6 + r, 23).Value > 0
    r = r + 1
Wend
k = 1
Li(k) = Sheets("UDL").Application.Max(Cells(6 + r, 18).Value, Lseg)
Cells(1 + k, 60).Value = 0
Cells(2 + k, 60).Value = 0.25 * Li(k)
Cells(3 + k, 60).Value = 0.5 * Li(k)
Cells(4 + k, 60).Value = 0.75 * Li(k)
Cells(5 + k, 60).Value = Li(k)
While k * Lseg < Li(1)
    k = k + 1
Wend
x1 = k * Lseg
x = x1
While Cells(6 + r, 23).Value <= 0
    r = r + 1
Wend
x2 = Cells(6 + r - 1, 18).Value
j = 1
While k * Lseg <= x2
    Cells(2 + 5 * j, 60).Value = x
    Cells(3 + 5 * j, 60).Value = x + 0.25 * Lseg
    Cells(4 + 5 * j, 60).Value = x + 0.5 * Lseg
    Cells(5 + 5 * j, 60).Value = x + 0.75 * Lseg
    Cells(6 + 5 * j, 60).Value = x + Lseg
    j = j + 1
    k = k + 1
    x = k * Lseg
Wend
If x2 = span Then
MsgBox (1)
    'Cells(2 + 5 * j, 60).Value = x
    'Cells(3 + 5 * j, 60).Value = x + 0.25 * (span - j * Lseg)
    'Cells(4 + 5 * j, 60).Value = x + 0.5 * (span - j * Lseg)
    'Cells(5 + 5 * j, 60).Value = x + 0.75 * (span - j * Lseg)
    'Cells(6 + 5 * j, 60).Value = x + (span - j * Lseg)
End If
End Sub
```

The problem is the last IF x2 = span THEN.
I used the MsgBox to display x2 and span just to double check, and they are exactly the same.
However, when I run the code it doesn't display 1.
I cannot work out why!
Any thought?

Thanks

Comment: Unless you reset r somehow, how do you have .Cells(6 + r, 23).Value > 0   in a loop where you add + 1 to r and then expect the following loop of   While .Cells(6 + r, 23).Value <= 0 to work? That looks odd. Also, please fully qualify your ranges i.e. use worksheet names in front of Cells / Ranges or use a With statement.  This line should be .Sheets("UDL").Application.Max(Sheets("UDL").Cells(6 + r, 18).Value, Lseg) to avoid using the implicit activesheet reference.

Comment: That, and declare your Integers as Long, aside, expecting us to debug this without any data is a pain especially as the code constantly references sheet values.